# Can't install Lubuntu

Tags: boot, partitioning

If you try and tell me to do a google search, then please tell me what search criteria to use.  This is a problem I've had for quite awhile.

I'm a linux newbie and am trying my best to not install Windows.

I bought a used Proliant Server (DL380 G5) that has Ubuntu loaded (Ubuntu 16.04.6 LTS, xenial) and is command line only.  I tried to install Lubuntu and it tells me I can't because I only have 8.0Gb available and it needs 8.6 gb.  I discovered it's loading/booting to a paging file.  My logical drive is 408 gigs.  I can run lubuntu from a flash drive, but it won't let me install any apps like Gparted.  The default partition utility acknowledges the paging file, but it doesn't see the rest of available storage.

Can anyone advise me on how to load a GUI OS?  I'm sorry if I don't know the correct questions to ask.

Thank you!

Comment: You haven't told us what release of Lubuntu you were trying to 'install'.  Servers like HP DL380 have a simple video card (very limited ram) as they are usually used headless and it's more efficient to run a server without any gui (your release would have told me LXQt or LXDE which would allow me to be more specific on graphic requirements). You could try `sudo apt install lubuntu-desktop` on your existing 16.04.6 LTS release (but note: LXDE/Lubuntu 16.04 had only 3 years of life so it's EOL this month; only server/Ubuntu or 'main' components (no flavor DE) have 5 years of support).

Comment: I agree with @guiverc here.  I work in a data center and these servers are not designed for everyday desktop use.  They are designed for backend data serving.  We will only plug a monitor into these servers for console access to change settings from a command line.  If we need any graphics, we will setup a web interface for them for access.

Answer (score 0):

You can *"cheat"* the installer by adding a thumb drive - That you wil not use! and install on your 8Gb partition.